# CodeLite does not recognize any c++ code

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, ide

I have just downloaded Code::Blocks on my new PC and written my hello world.
My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "hello world!";
return 0;
}
```

My text does not get highlighted and when I tried to build and run the program this appeared in the terminal:

```
                      sh: 1: /directory/I/saved/in/helloworld: Permission denied

                      process returned 126 (0x7E)  execution time : 0.002 s
                      Press Enter to continue.
```

My compiler is gcc and I had the same problem in CodeLite. How can I fix it?

Comment: What are other files in saved/in directory? I suspect that you named your file without an extension, and you try to execute your source file.

Comment: There were no other files, but you were right, I thought the extension wouldhave been added automaticly, but when I checked my file did not have an extension. When I saved it as helloworld.cpp all my code got highlighted correctly and the program was executable! thx a lot for the quick help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to sum it up:
All I had to do was add an extension (in my case ".cpp") to my file, so it would be executable.